# Celery revocations are lost on rabbitMQ restart

Tags: python, celery

We're using celery eta tasks to schedule tasks FAR (like months) in the future.
Now using the rabbitMQ backend because the mongo backend did loose such tasks on a worker restart.

Actually tasks with the rabbitMQ backend seem to be persistent across celery and rabbitMQ restarts, BUT **revoke** messages seem to be lost on rabbitMQ restarts.
I guess that if revoke messages are lost, those eta tasks that should be killed will execute anyway.

Comment: No, it's actually the celery worker restart that looses the revocations list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be helpful from the documentation ([Persistent Revokes](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#persistent-revokes)):

> The list of revoked tasks is in-memory so if all workers restart the
>   list of revoked ids will also vanish. If you want to preserve this
>   list between restarts you need to specify a file for these to be
>   stored in by using the –statedb argument to celery worker:

```
$ celery -A proj worker -l info --statedb=/var/run/celery/worker.state
```